# how to get all the rows as well as the column headers from the datagrid to a list

Tags: c#

I am currently working on wingrid. In that.. after the data getting displayed in the wingrid, i want to take all the rows from the grid to new list including the column header.

In windows datagrid we will take the column header like this.

List cols = new List();
        // populate
        foreach (ColumnHeader column in Datagrid.Columns) {
            cols.Add(column);
        }

but in wingrid there is no class called columnHeader...

Kindly tell me how to take the columns name as well as the rows from the grid to the new list..

Regards,

Ram N

Comment: Are you talking about the WinForms Datagrid that ships with .NET, or are you using the UltraWinGrid from Infragistics?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the default System.Windows.Forms.Datagrid then it would be the [MappingName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridcolumnstyle.mappingname.aspx) or [HeaderText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridcolumnstyle.headertext.aspx) property of the [DataGridColumnStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7dyk6053.aspx) objects held in the [GridColumnStyles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridtablestyle.gridcolumnstyles.aspx) property of the active [DataGridTableStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridtablestyle.aspx) in the [Datagrid.TableStyles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.tablestyles.aspx) property.

If by 'wingrid' you mean the Infagistics WinGrid (Infagistics.Win.UltraWingrid) then the Columns (a [ColumnsCollection](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/NET/2008.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v8.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnsCollection.html)) property of the active [UltraGridBand](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/NET/2008.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v8.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridBand.html) in the Bands collection of the active [UltraGridLayout](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/NET/2008.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v8.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridLayout.html) in the Layouts collection of the [UltraGrid](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/NET/2008.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v8.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGrid.html) object seems to be what you're after.